Unable to complete the setup initial for WordPress block plugin
I created my WordPress site using local. There is no plugin installed on the website.
My Node version is 20.17.0 and my NPM version is 10.8.3
My WordPress version is 6.6.2
I execute the following command from the cmd in the plugin directory.
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest copyright-date-block --variant=dynamic
cd copyright-date-block

This is what I get in the terminal after executing the command:
Creating a new WordPress plugin in the copyright-date-block directory.

Creating a "block.json" file.

Creating a "package.json" file.

Installing `@wordpress/scripts` package. It might take a couple of minutes...

Formatting JavaScript files.

Compiling block.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:59
                error = new Error(message);
                        ^

Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build

> copyright-date-block@0.1.0 build
> wp-scripts build --webpack-copy-php

assets by status 7.9 KiB [cached] 6 assets
Entrypoint view = view.js view.asset.php
Entrypoint index = index.js index.asset.php
./src/view.js 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
./src/index.js 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL]: Cannot find module './polyfill-exclusions'

// More lines

webpack 5.94.0 compiled with 2 errors in 941 ms
    at makeError (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\execa\index.js:114:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\@wordpress\create-block\lib\init-wp-scripts.js:31:2)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\@wordpress\create-block\lib\scaffold.js:156:4)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\@wordpress\create-block\lib\index.js:120:6) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build',
  command: 'npm run build',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.
